# Why C program prints blank line to file?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, file-io

I have the following C code which writes words given to program to file called "command.txt". If word is "quit" program ends, else it prints the word and writes it to file. However, if the word is "file" it gets the first word on the first line of file by using function getstring() and continues to next loop iteration. This word is then used on this new round and the code goes straight to "else"-branch and should print out the word and write it to file again.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


void getstring(char **p) {
    char string[100];
    char *word = NULL;
    FILE *file = fopen("command.txt", "r");
    fgets(string, 100, file);
    word = strtok(string," \n");
    p[0] = word;
    fclose(file);
}

void writetofile (char **strarr) {
    FILE *file = fopen("command.txt", "a");
    fprintf(file, "%s\n", strarr[0]);
    fclose(file);
}

int main(void) {

    char line[100];
    char *word = NULL;
    char *strarr[5];
    char **p = NULL;
    int flag = 0, i;

    while (1) {
        if (flag == 1) {
            flag = 0;
        }
        else {
            printf("Give string: ");
            fgets(line, 100, stdin);
            word = strtok(line," \n");
            strarr[0] = word;
        }

        if (strcmp(strarr[0], "quit") == 0) {
            break;
        }
        else if (strcmp(strarr[0], "file") == 0) {
            p = strarr;
            getstring(p);
            flag = 1;
            continue;
        }
        else {
            printf("Text: %s\n", strarr[0]);
            writetofile(strarr);
        }

        for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
            strarr[i] = NULL;
        }
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is this: if I type in "file" nothing is written to the file. For example, if I give the words "hello", "file" and "world" and then quit the program the printout looks like this:

```
Give string: hello
Text: hello
Give string: file
Text: hello
Give string: world
Text: world
Give string: quit
```

command.txt looks like this:

```
hello

world
```

So, there's an empty line where should be another "hello". Why is this? Am I missing something obvious here or is this because of the way pointers are used?

Comment: Use a debugger to inspect the data pointed to by `word` after the `strtok` call. There's probably still a carriage return (`\r`) at the end causing the `strcmp` to not match.

Comment: these lines: word = strtok(line," \n");
            strarr[0] = word; always set strarr[0] to point to the first char in the line[] array   I.E. &line[0].  so it would be clearer to simply say strarr[0] = line;

Comment: the array of char pointers strarr[5] only had one pointer ever set. I.E. strarr[0], so there is no need for the loop that sets all the pointers to null, nor any use for anything beyond char *strarr.  Then always reference it as strarr.  the char **p = NULL and all references to p server no purpose, so replace all references to p with strarr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once possible issue is that you are returning a pointer to a local variable in `getstring()`:

```
void getstring(char **p) {
    char string[100];
    char *word = NULL;
    ...
    word = strtok(string," \n"); 
    p[0] = word;                 //word points into string[] which is a local
    ...
}
```

After your return from `getstring()` the local variable `string[]` is not longer valid and thus accessing `p[0]` later on is undefined behaviour.

To fix this either copy the word into a fixed buffer or allocate the memory for the return string.

Comment: That's definitely the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char * getstring(void);
void   writetofile(char *);

char * getstring()
{
    static char fileString[100];
    memset( fileString, 0x00, sizeof( fileString ) );
    FILE *fp = fopen("command.txt", "r");
    if( NULL == fp )
    {
        perror( "fopen" );
        strcat( fileString, "ERROR: failed to open file: command.txt for read\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        if( NULL == fgets(fileString, 100, fp) )
        { // then read error or file empty
            perror( "fgets" );
            strcat( fileString, "I/O error occurred\n" );
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return( &fileString[0] );
}

void writetofile (char *stringToWrite)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("command.txt", "a");
    if( NULL == fp )
    {
        perror( "fopen" );
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%s\n", stringToWrite);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}

int main()
{

    char line[100];

    while (1)
    {

        printf("Give string: ");
        if( NULL == fgets(line, 100, stdin) )
        {
            perror( "fgets" );
        }
        else
        { // then successful read of string from user

            if( NULL == strtok(line," \n") )
            {
                perror( "strtok" );
            }
            else
            { // else found/replaced trailing newline

                if (strcmp(line, "quit") == 0)
                { // then user wants to exit pgm
                    break;
                }

                // implied else

                if (strcmp(line, "file") == 0)
                { // then user wants to use first line of file.
                    // get/save first line from file
                    strcpy( line, getstring() );
                    printf("Text: %s", line ); // note: line already contains '\n'
                    // append line to file
                    writetofile( line );
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Text: %s\n", line );
                    // append line to file
                    writetofile( line );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return( 0 );
}
```

Comment: It is generally helpful if you explain why your answer solves the problem rather than simply dumping a big code snippet

Comment: I got the solution to fix the problem in my own code already. Thanks for effort though.